# Highlighting the subsequence in a plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: shapelets]

How can I highlight a subsequence as shown in this image where a certain part is highlighted with different color than rest of the plot with Matplotlib?

I am trying to plot a time series where I have a certain area of interest, which I would like to highlight in different color. For that specific area I already have a index number so lets say with index number(203) + (a window size of specific length= 40).

How can I plot it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: ① plot `x` vs `y` using `zorder=3` ② plot `x[i:j]`vs `y[i:j]` using `zorder=4`